# how can i draw canvas on the current window? (not use setContentView)

Tags: android

here is my code

```
        String station_in_course = "";
        for(String data : exStation)
            station_in_course = station_in_course + data + " ";
        station_in_course = station_in_course + endStationNM + "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < StationNMArray.size(); i++) {
            String current_Station = StationNMArray.get(i);

            station_in_course = station_in_course + "\nStation: " + current_Station
                    + "\nDate: " + year + "년 " +  month + "월 " +  day + "일"
                    + "\nTime: " + currentHourArray.get(i) + "시 " + currentMinArray.get(i) + "분"
                    + "\n예측값: " + currentPredict.get(i) + "\n";
            CircleChart cc = new CircleChart(this, currentPredict.get(i), 100*i, 500*i);
//            setContentView(cc);
            cc.onDraw();

        }
```

but this code not working

if I use `setContentView` then open new window(pop-up) and draw canvas `CircleChart`

but I want to draw canvas `CircleChart` current window

how can I solve this problem?

My repository is [full link](https://github.com/Lay4U/CapstOne/tree/master/SC/MySubwayProject_HL)

for reference CircleChart code is

```
package com.example.mysubwayproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;

import com.example.mysubwayproject.WritingVO;

public class CircleChart extends View{


    float predict = 0;
    int x ;
    int y ;

    public  CircleChart(Context context, float predict, int x, int y ) {
        super(context);
        this.predict = predict;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public void onDraw() {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        //drawArc를 이용하면 오른쪽이 0도가 된다. 난 가장 윗부분을 0도로 보았기 때문에 -90도를 해주었다.
        final float START_POINT = -90f;

        //이 그래프에서 만점이 100점이기 때문에 100등분을 해야 한다. 그래서 360도를 100으로 나누었다. 만약 5등분을 하고싶다면 360/5를 하면 된다.
        final float ANGLE_PER_SCORE = (float)360/250;
        Log.i("쉬비", ANGLE_PER_SCORE+"");
        //획득한 점수를 퍼센트로 나타냄
        float successPoint =  predict;
        Log.i("쉬비", successPoint+"");
        successPoint = Math.round(successPoint*10);
        Log.i("쉬비", successPoint+"");
        successPoint = successPoint/(float)10.0;
        Log.i("쉬비", successPoint+"");

        //획득한 점수 부분의 각 (획득한 점수의 퍼센트 * 1점당 각도)
        float angle = successPoint;
        int x2 = x+500;
        int y2 = y+500;

        //사각형 객체 RectF를 생성, 원형 그래프의 크기를 사각형이라 보고 좌,상,우,하 좌표 설정, 좌상이 기준이 된다.
        RectF rectF = new RectF(x,x,y,y);
        RectF rectF2 = new RectF(x2,x2,y2,y2);

        //페인트 객체 생성
        Paint p = new Paint();

        //페인트 객체 설정
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(y/6);
        p.setAlpha(0x00);
        p.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        //원형 그래프의 회색 부분 설정
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, START_POINT, -360 + angle , false, p);

        //페인트 객체 설정
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT );

        //원형 그래프의 빨간 부분 설정
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, START_POINT, angle, false, p);
        Log.i("쉬비", angle+"");

        //페인트 객체를 다시 설정한 다음 캔버스에 글씨를 쓴다.
        p.reset();
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        //캔버스에 그릴 글씨의 길이에 맞게 글씨 크기 및 위치를 조정
        if(successPoint>=10){
            p.setTextSize(y/4);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(successPoint), (float)((x+y)/4), (float)((x+y)/1.7), p);
            p.setTextSize(y/6);
            canvas.drawText("%", (float)((x+y)/4+(y/4*1.9)), (float)((x+y)/1.7), p);
        }else if(successPoint<10){
            p.setTextSize(y/4);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(successPoint), (float)((x+y)/3.2), (float)((x+y)/1.7), p);
            p.setTextSize(y/6);
            canvas.drawText("", (float)((x+y)/4+(y/4*1.8)), (float)((x+y)/1.7), p);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why you have implemented view constructor in a such way?

Comment: Is there another way? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Yeap, there are few problems in your constructor: 1) you had not override another 3 constructors 2) by implementing such a constructor you cannot inflate your view from xml (if this params will be in another one constructors)

Comment: I need pie chart to visualize data

Comment: `super(context);
        this.predict = predict;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;` here?

Answer (score 0):

You should add view with the screen-size bounds. It would be the right way to solve this one problem.

So, your custom view will call cc.draw in onDraw method

Comment: Can you give me some example, please?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view - this one tutorial is about view creating, implement you constructor with attrs parameter and then simply inflate your view from xml file

Comment: I did     `public  CircleChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }` and make xml file?

Comment: Yeap, and all your attributes place in attrs file. Then you may add this in your activity xml file and work with them as usual android view

Comment: it's very difficult for me, I'll try and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I may share with your link to my repository with custom views examples

Comment: I am very grateful for your kindness.

Comment: So, really no problems ;P This one project is about custom views: https://github.com/st235/LayoutPlusViews

Comment: when i add layout xml to LinearLayout the error is occur ```'layout_height' attribute should be defined more... (Ctrl+F1) 'layout_width' attribute should be defined more... (Ctrl+F1) Element LinearLayout doesn't have required attribute android:layout_height more... (Ctrl+F1) Element LinearLayout doesn't have required attribute android:layout_width more... (Ctrl+F1)```

Comment: Yeap, u should specify your views sizes

Comment: almost I'd like you to hold on a minute.

Comment: I did push to my repository but, i don't know `CircleChart`'s parameter

Comment: Do u have a telegram account? Can we discuss it there? May u share it with me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194373/discussion-between-gobackess-and-alexander-dadukin).

Comment: I open discussion in chat